# How to apply the ItemAdd event to a folder at the same level as the inbox?

Tags: vba, outlook

I've been able to forward a message with custom text added when it hits my inbox.

I need messages from a folder other than my inbox to be forwarded.

I receive notifications from Box, and I've set up a routing for those messages to be directed to a "BoxNotifications" folder. That folder is at the same level as the Inbox.

I don't understand what needs to be done, even after searching extensively.

What would I need to get messages that enter the "BoxNotifications" folder to be forwarded with custom text?

```
Public WithEvents objInbox As Outlook.Folder
Public WithEvents objInboxItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set objInbox = Outlook.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set objInboxItems = objInbox.Items
End Sub

Private Sub objInboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objForward As Outlook.MailItem

    If TypeOf Item Is MailItem Then
       Set objMail = Item

       'If it is a specific new email
       If (objMail.SenderEmailAddress = "senderemail@gmail.com") And (objMail.Subject Like "*Test*") Then

           Set objForward = objMail.Forward
           'Customize the forward subject, body and recipients
           With objForward
                .Subject = "Testing Email"
                .HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>Custom text added to top of email</BODY></HTML>" & objForward.HTMLBody
                .Recipients.Add ("email_forwarded_to@email.com")
                .Recipients.ResolveAll
                .Importance = olImportanceHigh
                .Send
           End With
       End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: have you tried  `Parent.Folders`?

Answer (score 0):

*Use [Folder.Parent property (Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Folder.Parent))*

*Example*

```
Set objInbox = Outlook.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("folder_name")
```